# How do I trigger an event listener in Java Discord-JDA specifically for MEMBER_VOICE_KICK action?

Tags: java, discord, bots, discord-jda

I have this event that has these problems.

1. It gets triggered whenever a new audit log gets created.
2. If a user enters voice-chat it gets triggered too

this the event listener

```java
   @Override
    public void onGuildAuditLogEntryCreate(GuildAuditLogEntryCreateEvent event) {
        JDA jda=event.getJDA();
        Guild gld=jda.getGuilds().get(0);

        AuditLogPaginationAction auditLogs = event.getGuild().retrieveAuditLogs();
        auditLogs.type(ActionType.MEMBER_VOICE_KICK);
        auditLogs.limit(1);
        auditLogs.queue( (entrys) ->
        {

            if (entrys.isEmpty()) return;
            AuditLogEntry entry = entrys.get(0);
            System.out.println("The User "+ entry.getUser().getId());
            Member member=gld.getMemberById(entry.getUser().getId());
            gld.modifyNickname(member,"User Voice kicker").queue();

        });
    }
```

**What i am aiming at:**

- I want it to specifically be triggered whenever a MEMBER_VOICE_KICK action happens. Only That

**What i tried:**

- I tried using the `onGuildVoiceUpdate()` event.... i got the same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The event already provides you the created entry, you can just look at that one specifically.

```java
public void onGuildAuditLogEntryCreate(GuildAuditLogEntryCreateEvent event) {
  AuditLogEntry entry = event.getEntry();
  if (entry.getType() != ActionType.MEMBER_VOICE_KICK) return; // guard case
  String userId = entry.getUserId();
  guild.retrieveMemberById(userId).flatMap(member ->
    member.modifyNickname("User Voice kicker")
  ).queue();
}
```

Comment: Can you explain what dose this line do `   gld.retrieveMemberById(userId).flatMap(member ->
              member.modifyNickname("User Voice kicker")
      ).queue();`

Comment: It retrieves the member and then updates the nickname

Comment: is there a way to make it always sync ? Because it only register's the voice kicker once. if the voice kicker kicks again it will not do anything. i have to turn the bot on and off again.